# Go logging wrapper that adds log levels

Tags: beginner, go, logging, library

The package is essentially a small wrapper around the stdlib logger that provides a very simple, easy to use logger that can toggle between different log levels (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR). Log levels control which log messages actually get written to the io.Writer. Also adds the ability to get new references/pointers to any previously instantiated loggers.

Mainly looking for feedback about things like concurrency safety and memory leaks, but any other feedback is also welcome.

Code:

```
//Package simplelog provides a simple, easy to use logger that can toggle between
//different log levels (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR). Most of the actual
//logging is done with the stdlib log.Logger, simplelog mainly controls
//controls which messages get written to logs via log levels.
package simplelog

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

//Log level constants
const (
    DEBUG   = 0
    INFO    = 10
    WARNING = 20
    ERROR   = 30
)

//Pkg level lock for reading and writing to the package level and
//a map of all logs. allLogs tracks all existing Loggers.
var (
    pkgLock sync.Mutex
    allLogs = make(map[string]*Logger)
)

//getfileinfo gets the calling filename and line number.
func getfileinfo() string {
    _, filename, line, ok := runtime.Caller(2)
    if !ok {
        filename = "Unknown"
        line = 0
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d: ", filepath.Base(filename), line)
}

type Logger struct {
    name          string      //The same string used when calling Get()
    level         int         //Determines which of the loggers are allowed to write data
    debugLogger   *log.Logger //Independent loggers for Independent prefixes/loglevels
    infoLogger    *log.Logger //Independent loggers for Independent prefixes/loglevels
    warningLogger *log.Logger //Independent loggers for Independent prefixes/loglevels
    errorLogger   *log.Logger //Independent loggers for Independent prefixes/loglevels
    logfileinfo   bool        //Whether or not to log the calling file and line number
    lock          sync.Mutex  //Extra concurrency protection
}

//SetLevel sets the log level for the respective Logger.
//Each level is an int that can be set via pkg constants
//e.g. (simplelog.DEBUG) or via literal ints. Messages sent
//to Loggers with a log level lower than the current level are
//not written.
func (logger *Logger) SetLevel(level int) {
    logger.lock.Lock()
    defer logger.lock.Unlock()
    logger.level = level
}

//Log level = 0 | simplelog.DEBUG
func (logger *Logger) Debug(msg string) {
    logger.lock.Lock()
    defer logger.lock.Unlock()
    if logger.level > DEBUG {
        return
    }
    if logger.logfileinfo {
        msg = getfileinfo() + msg
    }
    logger.debugLogger.Println(msg)
}

//Log level = 10 | simplelog.INFO
func (logger *Logger) Info(msg string) {
    logger.lock.Lock()
    defer logger.lock.Unlock()
    if logger.level > INFO {
        return
    }
    if logger.logfileinfo {
        msg = getfileinfo() + msg
    }
    logger.infoLogger.Println(msg)
}

//Log level = 20 | simplelog.WARNING
func (logger *Logger) Warning(msg string) {
    logger.lock.Lock()
    defer logger.lock.Unlock()
    if logger.level > WARNING {
        return
    }
    if logger.logfileinfo {
        msg = getfileinfo() + msg
    }
    logger.warningLogger.Println(msg)
}

//Log level = 30 | simplelog.ERROR
func (logger *Logger) Err(msg string) {
    logger.lock.Lock()
    defer logger.lock.Unlock()
    if logger.level > ERROR {
        return
    }
    if logger.logfileinfo {
        msg = getfileinfo() + msg
    }
    logger.errorLogger.Println(msg)
}

/*
New is the constructor for simplelog. It returns a pointer to a lvlLogger.
    name - Can be used to get a new pointer to an existing log via simplelog.Get(name)
    dest - Sets the destination to which log messages will be written
    logfileinfo - Whether or not to include filename:line in message (e.g. main.go:30)
    flags - The same flags you would pass into the stdlib log.New()
        Defaults to "log.Ldate | log.Ltime | log.Lmsgprefix" if nothing is passed.
        `log.Lshortfile` will always report as this pkg, so use logfileinfo param instead.

*/
func New(name string, dest io.Writer, logfileinfo bool, flags ...int) *Logger {
    pkgLock.Lock()
    defer pkgLock.Unlock()
    _, alreadyExists := allLogs[name]
    if alreadyExists {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("simplelog: Unable to create logger with name \"%s\", name already in use", name))
    }
    var logflags int
    if flags == nil {
        logflags = log.Ldate | log.Ltime | log.Lmsgprefix
    } else {
        logflags = flags[0]
    }
    debugLogger := log.New(dest, "DEBUG: ", logflags)
    infoLogger := log.New(dest, "INFO: ", logflags)
    warningLogger := log.New(dest, "WARNING: ", logflags)
    errorLogger := log.New(dest, "Error: ", logflags)
    returnlogger := &Logger{
        name:          name,
        debugLogger:   debugLogger,
        infoLogger:    infoLogger,
        warningLogger: warningLogger,
        errorLogger:   errorLogger,
        logfileinfo:   logfileinfo,
    }
    allLogs[name] = returnlogger
    return returnlogger
}

//Get returns a reference to an existing Logger if one exists, otherwise nil.
//Uses the name string that was used to create the log via simplelog.New()
func Get(name string) *Logger {
    pkgLock.Lock()
    defer pkgLock.Unlock()
    if foundlog, isfound := allLogs[name]; isfound {
        return foundlog
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    "simplelog"
)

func main() {
    logfile, _ := os.OpenFile("testlog.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0777)
    mylogger := simplelog.New("Mylog", logfile, true)
    mylogger.SetLevel(simplelog.DEBUG)
    mylogger.Debug("First msg")
    mylogger.Info("First msg")
    mylogger.Warning("First msg")
    mylogger.Err("First msg")

    anotherPointer := simplelog.Get("Mylog")
    anotherPointer.Info("Another pointer")
    anotherPointer.Info("--------------")

    anotherPointer.SetLevel(simplelog.WARNING)
    anotherPointer.Debug("Warnings and higher")
    anotherPointer.Info("Warnings and higher")
    anotherPointer.Warning("Warnings and higher")
    anotherPointer.Err("Warnings and higher")
}
```

testlog.txt output:

```
2022/01/14 12:13:03 DEBUG: testapp.go:13: First msg
2022/01/14 12:13:03 INFO: testapp.go:14: First msg
2022/01/14 12:13:03 WARNING: testapp.go:15: First msg
2022/01/14 12:13:03 ERROR: testapp.go:16: First msg
2022/01/14 12:13:03 INFO: testapp.go:19: Another pointer
2022/01/14 12:13:03 INFO: testapp.go:20: --------------
2022/01/14 12:13:03 WARNING: testapp.go:25: Warnings and higher
2022/01/14 12:13:03 ERROR: testapp.go:26: Warnings and higher
```

To stdout with no flags:

```
mylogger := simplelog.New("naked logger", os.Stdout, false, 0)
mylogger.Info("Just a prefix")
```

Stdout:

```
INFO: Just a prefix
```

Answer (score 1):

Is file size a concern in your context? 
Perhaps to include a maximum size in bytes for your files could be a useful constraint.